# How to get active port information (recreate `netstat command`) in Solaris with C++?

Tags: c++, networking, port, solaris, netstat

I want to recreate the netstat command using C++ in order to get all active port information (specifically `netstat -f <unix/inet/inet6> -u`). I've done this on Windows, Linux, and macOS. On Linux, which I thought would be most similar to Solaris, I parsed /proc/net/tcp etc to get this information. This file doesn't exist in Solaris and I can't find anything similar. I can't figure out what exactly netstat on Solaris is doing to get it's information.

`man netstat` says at the bottom "The netstat utility obtains TCP statistics from the system by opening /dev/tcp and issuing queries". `/dev/tcp` is a sym link tp `devices/pseudo/tcp@0:tcp` and I'm not quite sure what that signifies or how to open and query it.

What functions/header files/files is Solaris' netstat using? What is it doing under the hood?

I've looked for the source code to it but can't seem to find anything other than dead links or links which redirect to Oracle's homepage. A working link to this source code would answer my question

Comment: Remember: On ***x like systems everything is a file.

Comment: Have you considered looking at the source code for the Solaris port of `netstat`? That's what I would do first.

Comment: OpenSolaris is opensource. Look at their netstat implementation at your leisure. Alternatively, `dtrace` netstat.

Comment: @JesperJuhl that was my first thought. However the links I came across were all dead. Those links being http://cvs.opensolaris.org/source/xref/netvirt/usr/src/cmd/cmd-inet/usr.bin/netstat/netstat.c and http://cvs.opensolaris.org/source/xref/netvirt/usr/src/cmd/cmd-inet/usr.bin/netstat/netstat.c. These were the only leads I could find when trying to find the source code.

Comment: @SergeyA do you know where that code is? The links that I find to their code either a) show a "We're sorry the java.net site has closed." or redirect to Oracle's home page

Comment: 10 seconds with Google found me this https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/52916131/ by searching for "illumos netstat source". Looks relevant.

Comment: @JesperJuhl link should be satisfying.

Comment: You can get a lot of this via SNMP in a platform-independent way.

Comment: The current illumos source for netstat is in https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/tree/master/usr/src/cmd/cmd-inet/usr.bin/netstat (illumos is the live fork of opensolaris).

Answer (score 1):

Solaris `/proc/` procfs has process information. Nothing else, or not much else. Linux extended it to include, really, system information of all kinds, not just processes.

You can always do obscure `ioctl()` of `/dev/tcp` to get your information. Better yet, you should be able to use SMF (Service Management Framework) to query properties of some network service to get your information (type `svcs` to get a list of services)